# Select XML Elements after last matching Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML file that looks like:

```
<Meal>
    <MealName>Lunch</MealName>
    <MealData>blahblahblah</MealData>
    <MealTime>2015-03-12</MealTime>
</Meal>
<Meal>
    <MealName>Dinner</MealName>
    <MealData>lolololol</MealData>
    <MealTime>2015-04-27</MealTime>
</Meal>
```

I'd like to select MealName and MealData of the last Meal instance.

I can do everything else I need with simple LINQ queries just fine. For example, to get data from last week's meals, I do:

```
XElement noIdea = XElement.Load(".../.../meal.xml");
DateTime d = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
int offset = d.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
        DateTime lastMonday = d.AddDays(-offset);
        DateTime lastSunday = lastMonday.AddDays(6);
        IEnumerable<XElement> idkMealTime =
                    from el in noIdea.Elements("Meal")
                    where DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(el.Element("MealTime").Value), lastMonday) > 0 &&
                    DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(el.Element("MealTime").Value), lastSunday) < 0
                    select el;
        WhatHaveYouEaten(idkMealTime);
```

But this one is different and I can't figure it out.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the select to `select new { MealName = (string)el.MealName("MealName"), MealData = (string)el.Element("MealData") };`?  That will give you an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is an anonymous type.

Comment: Can't you just use `var meal = noIdea.Descendants("Meal").Last()` and then get the relevant child elements from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select the last meal element:

```
var lastMeal = noIdea.Elements("Meal").Last();
```

As an aside, you can simply cast an element to `DateTime` rather than converting the string value - e.g. `(DateTime)el.Element("MealTime")`.  This uses `DateTime.Parse` internally with the correct styles as allowed in the XML specification.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed Last when looking for the last element... Can you explain how `(DateTime)el.Element("MealTime")` actually works, without even using .Value - any documentation on it? Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, they are explicit type conversions.  The implemented conversion are [detailed in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933(v=vs.110).aspx).  They're often more useful then using `.Value` as casting to a nullable type or to a reference type avoids the need to check if the element is `null`.  [This blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx) explains it all quite nicely.

Comment: The actual implementation is in [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,4792)

Comment: Just read the article and changed my code from (example 1): `lastMeal.Element("MealName").Value` to `(string)lastMeal.Element("MealName")` and (example 2) `decimal.Parse(lastMeal.Element("MealTotalCaloriesCarbs").Value) / 4` to `(decimal)lastMeal.Element("MealTotalCaloriesCarbs") / 4`. It comes in handy because my xml file has undergone many changes and missing elements no longer throw exceptions. Thanks for the link.